# How to convert integral number passed as parameter to String

Tags: java

I am working on program and I am struck at this point /

```
 public static int numOutput( Integer.toString(int number))
   {
      String outputNumber="";
      if (outputNumber.length()<=10)
      {
          outputNumber.concat(number);
      }
     else
     {
         return  outputNumber;
     }
   }
```

How can I fix this??

Comment: Why are you calling `toString` in the argument list? Just call that in the body of the function.

Comment: You are trying to return a String in an int function. Change the first line into public static String...

Comment: What the **** is that function supposed to do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. `Integer.toString(int number)` should be in the body of the method, not in the argument declaration.
2. Are you trying to concat the number passed to an empty String? Just use take `Integer.toString(number)` or `number + ""`
3. You must return an integer as you have declared that. Either change the return type to String or change the values returned to an int.
4. You check the length of an empty string. It will **always** be less than 10.

   ```
   public static int numOutput(int number) {
       String outputNumber = "";
       if (outputNumber.length()<=10) {
           outputNumber = number + "";
       } else {
           return number;
       }
       return -1;
   }
   ```